# How to write batch file to retsart services with varying names

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file, cmd, prompt

I'm trying to write a batch file that will restart a service from a program my company uses called Bomgar that allows our help desk technicians to remote into an employees computer. I know how to write a batch file that restarts services, the problem is that each service has a unique number ID on it (example; bomgar-ps-10000000-10000000) that is completely different machine to machine. Is there a way to restart services whose name falls within a "range"? Say any service whose name contains "bomgar-ps" as an example.

Really not sure how to handle this. The problem we're having is that this service is failing to start up occasionally and when an employee calls with a problem, they aren't tech savvy so a lot of time is wasted trying to guide them into services.msc and manually restarting the service.

Answer (score 1):

This should work also.

```
@echo off
set "servicename="
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('net start ^| find /i "bomgar-ps") do set "servicename=%%a"
if defined servicename net stop "%servicename%"
ping -n 3 localhost >nul
net start "%servicename%"
echo servicename "%servicename%" has attempted to restart
```

If you are merely guiding someone over the phone to restart the service then this will print the name to the console, in a fairly simple manner (add /i to the find command if `bomgar` can be mixed case"

```
net start|find "bomgar"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll be testing this as soon as I can on a normal workstation but it appeared to work on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I used it to search for the print spooler name and restart it. You should be able to replace spool with boomgar-ps, you may even be able to remove the SERVICE_NAME: part.

```
@ECHO OFF
>%TEMP%\~sc.log (sc queryex type= service state= all)
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=: " %%I in ('type %TEMP%\~sc.log^|find "SERVICE_NAME: Spool"') do set scname=%%J
ECHO RESTARTING %scname%
sc stop %scname%
sc start %scname%
```